# JavaScript Multiple Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to add multiple sliders to one HTML page. I'm using a template to construct the site from (currently more for speed than anything!) and it gives the refine slide java script (as below). This works on all pages with one slider, I'm trying to adjust it to add two more sliders onto the same page. Both to be sized using span spaces but I cant see the best way to adjust it to add in the new ones. I tried to add it in as another element hence 'rs-slider, rs-slider1' - the first one work perfectly but I cant seem to get the other to add correctly and just wind up with list elements. Any help appreciated as always!

I thought it would need to be declared as below but I may be entirely mistaken:

```
// RS (RefineSlide) object constructor
function RS(elem, settings) {
    this.$slider            = $(elem).addClass('rs-slider, rs-slider1');      // Elem: Slider element
    this.settings           = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);    // Obj: Merged user settings/defaults
    this.$slides            = this.$slider.find('> li');           // Elem Arr: Slide elements
    this.totalSlides        = this.$slides.length;                 // Int: Number of slides
    this.cssTransitions     = testBrowser.cssTransitions();        // Bool: Test for CSS transition support
    this.cssTransforms3d    = testBrowser.cssTransforms3d();       // Bool: Test for 3D transform support
    this.currentPlace       = this.settings.startSlide;         // Int: Index of current slide (starts at 0)
    this.$currentSlide      = this.$slides.eq(this.currentPlace);  // Elem: Starting slide
    this.inProgress         = false;                               // Bool: Prevents overlapping transitions
    this.$sliderWrap        = this.$slider.wrap('<div class="rs-wrap" />').parent();      // Elem: Slider wrapper div
    this.$sliderBG          = this.$slider.wrap('<div class="rs-slide-bg" />').parent();  // Elem: Slider background (useful for styling & essential for cube transitions)
    this.settings.slider = this;  // Make slider object accessible to client call code with 'this.slider' (there's probably a better way to do this)

    this.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing somewhere in your code you have something that looks like this:

```
$(someElement).refineSlide();
```

You just need another one of those with the other element.

Comment: Correct, so where I have $.data(this, 'refineslide', new RS(this, refineslide1) for the new one for example??

Comment: Something similar to that.  You'll have to look at the code surrounding that line.  `this` depends on the context.  In this example it's referring to the element, but you want to refer to the second element instead.

Comment: That I think I can see, so the surrounding is an if statement, 

// jQuery plugin wrapper
 $.fn['refineSlide'] = function (settings) {
  return this.each(function () {
            // Check if already instantiated on this elem
   if (!$.data(this, 'refineSlide')) {
                // Instantiate & store elem + string
    $.data(this, 'refineSlide', new RS(this, settings));
   }
  });
so if refineslide is already there we want to initiate refineslide1 which would refer to the new RS, or would that still look back to the initial refineslide

Comment: Never mind, don't do what I said.  This is intended to be used as a jQuery plugin.  See my edit.

Comment: So adding that at the end of whats there already would allow it to start the new refineslide1 but would it still allow it to behave the same as the first refine slide would? (sorry dont know if I'm making sense)

Comment: Find the place in your code where `.refineSlide()` gets called on the one element, and do the same thing but with the other element.  If you pass it the same settings object, it should behave the same.